# Cross product of a vector in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following vectors (essentially`2x1` matrices):

```
a = sc.array([[1], [2], [3]])
>>> a
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]]

b = sc.array([[4], [5], [6]])
>>> b
[[4]
 [5]
 [6]]
```

The cross product of these vectors can be calculated using `numpy.cross()`. Why does this not work:

```
import numpy as np 

np.cross(a, b)
ValueError: incompatible dimensions for cross product
(dimension must be 2 or 3)
```

but this does?:

```
np.cross(a.T, b.T)
[[-3  6 -3]]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To compute the cross product using `numpy.cross`, the dimension (length) of the array dimension which defines the two vectors must either by two or three. To quote the documentation:

> If `a` and `b` are arrays of vectors, the vectors
>       are defined by the last axis of `a` and `b` by default, and these axes
>       can have dimensions 2 or 3.

Note that the last axis is the default. In your example:

```
In [17]: a = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])

In [18]: b = np.array([[4], [5], [6]])

In [19]: print a.shape,b.shape
(3, 1) (3, 1)
```

the last axis is only of length 1, so the cross product is not defined. However, if you use the transpose, the length along the last axis is 3, so it is valid. You could also do:

```
In [20]: np.cross(a,b,axis=0)
Out[20]: 
array([[-3],
       [ 6],
       [-3]])
```

which tells `cross` that the vectors are defined along the first axis, rather than the last axis.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Is it possible to change the default axis to 0?

Comment: @thomas: Not that I am aware of. But is it really such an arduous task to either follow the conventions of the library when defining your vectors, or to explicitly define their order to the call?

Comment: No it is not, but I am writing code for some students and by vexperience it confuses them if for example vectors are all row vectors when they are used to column vectors.

Comment: Is there a reason that the vector size is limited to 2 or 3?

Answer (score 5):

In numpy we often use 1d arrays to represent vectors, and we treat it as either a row vector or a column vector depending on the context, for example:

```
In [13]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [15]: b = np.array([4, 5, 6])

In [16]: np.cross(a, b)
Out[16]: array([-3,  6, -3])

In [17]: np.dot(a, b)
Out[17]: 32
```

You can store vectors as 2d arrays, this is most useful when you have a collection of vectors you want to treat in a similar way. For example if I want to cross 4 vectors in a with 4 vectors in b. By default numpy assumes the vectors are along the last dimensions but you can use the axisa and axisb arguments to explicitly specify that the vectors are along the first dimension.

```
In [26]: a = np.random.random((3, 4))

In [27]: b = np.random.random((3, 4))

In [28]: np.cross(a, b, axisa=0, axisb=0)
Out[28]: 
array([[-0.34780508,  0.54583745, -0.25644455],
       [ 0.03892861,  0.18446659, -0.36877085],
       [ 0.36736545,  0.13549752, -0.32647531],
       [-0.46253185,  0.56148668, -0.10056834]])
```

Comment: Bago raises the point here. Numpy is not MATLAB, you can (and should) forget about columns and rows because arrays are a computational concept and don't have it. Matrices do.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a and b like this:

```
a = sc.array([1, 2, 3])
b = sc.array([4, 5, 6])
```

so that they have dimension = 3.